# How can I redraw a RMShape when I drag an annotation?

Tags: ios, mapbox

In one of my apps, I need to draw a line between 2 RMPointAnnotation. 
What I've done is I create everything in the viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    RMPointAnnotation *annotation = [[RMPointAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView
                                                                    coordinate:self.mapView.centerCoordinate
                                                                      andTitle:@"annotation"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    RMPointAnnotation *annotation2 = [[RMPointAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView
                                                                     coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude - 0.005, self.mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude + 0.005)
                                                                       andTitle:@"annotation 2"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation2];

    RMAnnotation *lineAnnotation = [[RMAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView coordinate:annotation.coordinate andTitle:nil];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:lineAnnotation];
}
```

and then I've implemented the mapView:layerForAnnotation:

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{
    if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation)
        return nil;

    RMShape *shape = [[RMShape alloc] initWithView:mapView];

    shape.lineColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    shape.lineWidth = 5.0;

    for (RMAnnotation *annotation in (NSArray *)mapView.annotations) {
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[RMPointAnnotation class]]) {
            [self.shape addLineToCoordinate:annotation.coordinate];
        }
    }

    return self.shape;
}
```

But because both of my RMPointAnnotation are draggable, I want to constantly redraw the line between the 2 annotations while dragging.

How can I achieve such thing with MapBox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So one way of working around this would be to create your own custom view that keeps up with your last location.

```
@implementation CMLPointView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width/2;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.lastLocation = self.center;
}
```

You can create a view for each point you need at a coordinate. I'm running this loop in my view controller so that I can handle the pan gesture from there.

```
for (CLLocation *loc in self.poiCoordinates) {
            CMLPointView *point = [[CMLPointView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([self.mapView coordinateToPixel:loc.coordinate].x-10.0f, [self.mapView coordinateToPixel:loc.coordinate].y-10.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f)];
            point.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
            [point addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

            [self.view addSubview:point];
}
```

And to actually handle the pan, I am creating a new RMAnnotation each time and drawing an RMShape for that annotation.

```
- (void)handlePan: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) pan
{
    CMLPointView *pointView = (CMLPointView *)pan.view;
    CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:self.view];
    pointView.center = CGPointMake(pointView.lastLocation.x + translation.x,
                              pointView.lastLocation.y + translation.y);

    // Just trying to remove the annotation for RMShape
    [self.mapView removeAnnotation:[self.mapView.annotations lastObject]];

    RMAnnotation *annotation = [[RMAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView coordinate:[self.mapView pixelToCoordinate:pointView.center] andTitle:@"POI"];
    [self.poiCoordinates removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [self.poiCoordinates insertObject:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[self.mapView pixelToCoordinate:pointView.center].latitude longitude:[self.mapView pixelToCoordinate:pointView.center].longitude] atIndex:0];
    annotation.userInfo = self.poiCoordinates;
    [annotation setBoundingBoxFromLocations:self.poiCoordinates];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Hope this helps! Please comment if you have a question of why I did something.

Comment: "Have you tried X?" isn't a good answer if you don't know if it will work. This should be a comment. Please read ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Best I could do right now. Can't comment on questions yet. And no one else was answering, so this vacant post wouldn't be bothered by an "incorrect type" of answer. Good luck to you.

Comment: Turns out, it works for me. Instead of RMPointAnnotations though, I am having to use a custom view.

Comment: That's great! Please update your answer and include any relevant code.